# Spark error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing a Scala/spark program which would find the max salary of the employee. The employee data is available in a CSV file, and the salary column has a comma separator for thousands and also it has a $ prefixed to it e.g. $74,628.00.

To handle this comma and dollar sign, I have written a parser function in scala which would split each line on "," and then map each column to individual variables to be assigned to a case class.

My parser program looks like below. In this to eliminate the comma and dollar signs I am using the replace function to replace it with empty, and then finally typecase to Int.

```
def ParseEmployee(line: String): Classes.Employee = {
    val fields = line.split(",")
    val Name = fields(0)
    val JOBTITLE = fields(2)
    val DEPARTMENT = fields(3)
    val temp = fields(4)

    temp.replace(",","")//To eliminate the ,
    temp.replace("$","")//To remove the $
    val EMPLOYEEANNUALSALARY = temp.toInt //Type cast the string to Int

    Classes.Employee(Name, JOBTITLE, DEPARTMENT, EMPLOYEEANNUALSALARY)
  }
```

My Case class look like below

```
case class Employee (Name: String,
                      JOBTITLE: String,
                     DEPARTMENT: String,
                     EMPLOYEEANNUALSALARY: Number,
)
```

My spark dataframe sql query looks like below

```
val empMaxSalaryValue = sc.sqlContext.sql("Select Max(EMPLOYEEANNUALSALARY) From EMP")
empMaxSalaryValue.show
```

when I Run this program I am getting this below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Number
- field (class: "java.lang.Number", name: "EMPLOYEEANNUALSALARY")
- root class: "Classes.Employee"
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:625)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$10.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:607)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:607)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders$.product(Encoders.scala:275)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:282)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:272)
    at CalculateMaximumSalary$.main(CalculateMaximumSalary.scala:27)
    at CalculateMaximumSalary.main(CalculateMaximumSalary.scala)
```

1. Any idea why I am getting this error? what is the mistake I am doing here and why it is not able to typecast to number?
2. Is there any better approach to handle this problem of getting maximum salary of the employee?

Comment: please provide codes for calling ParseEmployee function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark SQL provides only a limited number of `Encoders` which target concrete classes. Abstract classes like `Number` are not supported (can be used with limited binary `Encoders`).

Since you convert to `Int` anyway, just redefine the class:

```
case class Employee (
  Name: String,
  JOBTITLE: String,
  DEPARTMENT: String,
  EMPLOYEEANNUALSALARY: Int
)
```

Comment: `BigDecimal` is much better suited for money since it can deal both with integer and decimal numbers with accuracy