# Cannot take first() of a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-scala

I am trying to use spark to load data from an s3 bucket into my emr notebook (which is on an emr cluster running spark 2.4)

I have the EMR notebook created and it creates a sparkSession as spark, and can assign

```
val connections = data.select("col1", "col2").rdd.distinct().flatMap(x => 
Iterable(x(0).asInstanceOf[Number].longValue, 
x(1).asInstanceOf[Number].longValue)).distinct().toDF()
```

I get the response

> connections: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: bigint]

which is expected, however when I then run:
    `connections.first()`

I get the output:

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 55, ip-10-0-251-222.ec2.internal, executor 4): java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Number` (plus about 100 more lines that it will not let me add)

​Why can I not take the first value of a dataframe full of bigints?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867882/spark-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception)

Comment: There should be no need to convert to an rdd, flatmap and the convert back to a dataframe. If you add some example input/expected output maybe a better solution can be found.

Answer (score 1):

Your starting DataFrame, data, has a String in it and that cannot be converted to a Number.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.Number...